# jQuery fade images in sequentially after JSON grab

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, timeout, fade

trying to fade these images in sequentially (one after the other) after they're grabbed from Flickr and assembled by jQuery. Currently, the code fades them in all together.

As I understand it, `imageL` is appended to the div one at a time because of the `each` function, so what I'm seeing is technically them fading in one after the other, it's just done super fast.

So where is a good place to put a time out? Or better yet, instead of putting space in the `each` function, how can I build them all, then simply fade them in one after another with a 100ms delay after they've been appended?

Thanks!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/RzkzY/16/

```
function imgBuilder(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo,function(i,rPhoto){
        var base   = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret,
        thumb  = base + '_m.jpg',
        large  = base + '_b.jpg',
        imageL = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ large +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>';

        $(imageL).appendTo("#test").animate({opacity:1},400);
    });
}

$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e3571d0891d2ad7f6b2b44611b8126ee&user_id=26545877%40N04&tags=terminal+5&per_page=25&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157629563488548-bdcd1a2ad2f288df&api_sig=92b8ac2a1dac669d39aa2170ec372012", imgBuilder);
```

​

Comment: I recommend doing the animation inside img.load event, because after you just set the src attribute of the image one after another, it'll fade automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(imageL).appendTo("#test").delay(400*i).animate({opacity:1},400);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the animate callback:

```
function imgBuilder(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo,function(i,rPhoto){
        var base   = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret,
        thumb  = base + '_m.jpg',
        large  = base + '_b.jpg',
        imageL = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ large +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>';

        $(imageL).appendTo("#test").hide();
    });

    callback = function() {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(1000, callback);
    };
    $('#test a:first').fadeIn(1000, callback);
}
```

I'm using fadeIn() here, but you could just as easily use animate() if you wanted to.

For the fiddlers out there: http://jsfiddle.net/luhn/hu76f/

Answer (score 0):

or make the animations synchronous with a flow control library like [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js):

```
function imgBuilder(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo,function(i,rPhoto){
        var base   = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret,
        thumb  = base + '_m.jpg',
        large  = base + '_b.jpg',
        imageL = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ large +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>';

        Frame(function(next){
            $(imageL).appendTo("#test").animate({opacity:1},400, next);
        });

    });
    Frame.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this to work reliably, you HAVE to wait until your images are loaded before trying to animate them.

Otherwise, the early ones will start animating before they are actually loaded and the viewer won't see the animation.  Unfortunately, that is a bit complicated to do.  Here's one way to do it.  When creating the image, a time is set on the object that is the desired animation time using jQuery's `.data()`.  Then, when the onload handler triggers, the current time is compared to the desired animation time and either the animation is started right away or it is schedule for a time in the future.  You should also note that proper testing for this condition requires clearing the browser memory and disk cache so you can see how it looks for a first time visitor before the images are cached.

This is the code for that:

```
function imgBuilder(data){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    $.each(data.photos.photo,function(i,rPhoto){
        var base = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret,
        thumb = base + '_m.jpg',
        large = base + '_b.jpg',
        link = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ large +'"></a>';

        /** something here **/
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var this$ = $(this);
            var animationTime = this$.data("fadeTime");
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            // if overdue for the animation, start it now
            if (now >= animationTime) {
                this$.fadeTo(400, 1);
            } else {
                // schedule it for later
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this$.fadeTo(400, 1);
                }, animationTime - now);
            }
        };
        img.alt = rPhoto.title;
        var link$ = $(link);
        link$.append(img);
        $(img)
            .data("fadeTime", now + (i * 400))
            .css("opacity", 0)
            .attr("src", thumb);
        link$.appendTo("#test");
    });
}

$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e3571d0891d2ad7f6b2b44611b8126ee&user_id=26545877%40N04&tags=terminal+5&per_page=25&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157629563488548-bdcd1a2ad2f288df&api_sig=92b8ac2a1dac669d39aa2170ec372012", imgBuilder);
```

And a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JKAQm/.